# How do I normalize dataset A to dataset B?

Tags: dictionary, location, dataset, mapping, normalization

I have two datasets of locational data; one is a created dataset with the list of every city in the world, and the other is locational data from user input.

I want to map all user input data to the complete dataset. For example, the user input data may have multiple lines:

- San Francisco
- San Fran
- SF

I want to map all of those rows to San Francisco, which is in the complete dataset.

What procedures, methods, tools, etc. would you recommend? I thought about regex but I don't know how to automate it to be able to search for all the different cities.

Clarification: The computer won't know whether or not something like SF is supposed to stand for San Francisco, that comes down to human judgement. In general, I'm looking for help on how to approach this problem. I don't know how to map one set to the other and that's the part I'm stuck on

Comment: Please be more specific about how you  want to connect the data. Is the computer supposed to know that "San Fran" and "San Francisco" are the same place because "Fran" is the first four letters of "Francisco"? How would it know that "SF" is "San Francisco" and not "San Fernando" or "Sfitzbergen" or "Spring Field"? Or were you planning to get a list of valid abbreviations somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for replying Jay! I guess what I'm stuck on is the tools for actually mapping San Fran to San Francisco. You're right in that I'll probably look @ the first few characters, but with abbreviations, I probably will do common ones by hand. I'm stuck on the method of approach more so than the smaller details.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I've taken so long to get back -- I selfishly went on vacation in there! If you're still working on this:

Okay, on the basics. Suppose you have a table named "place" and a field named "city". You could do a simple match on the first however-many characters with the "like" operator.

```
select <whatever> from place where city like 'San Fran%';
```

You probably want to ignore case, so "san fran" will match San Francisco. In that case:

```
select <whatever> from place where upper(city) like upper('San Fran%');
```

Of course in real life you wouldn't hard-code the "San Fran", it would be a run-time parameter.

Create an index on city and that would be very fast. If you use the "upper" to make it case insensitive, then create an index on upper(city).

Okay, so you also want to handle another case: abbreviations, like "SF" for San Francisco.

You don't say what flavor of SQL you're using. If it supports functions, you could write a function that would form an abbreviation from any name. The function could look scan through the characters of the name with substring (or whatever equivalent your SQL has -- I think these functions are not very standard), look for spaces, and pull the first character and then every character that follows a space, then return that. Let's say you call this function "abbreviate()". Then the query would be:

```
select <whatever> from place where upper(city) like concat(@city,'%') or abbreviate(city) = @city;
```

(The above is what it would look like in MS SQL Server, where parameters have names that begin with an "@".)

You would then create indexes on upper(city) and abbreviate(city) to keep it fast.

If you want to be more flexible than that, well, I don't think there's any way around considering every case you want to handle. Like if you want the user to be able to enter "frisco" and find San Francisco, or "vegas" to get Las Vegas, you could search for the entered string anywhere in the city name, i.e. "city like '%frisco%'". But there are two big problems with that. One, I think you'll get a lot of false hits, probably many of them rather mysterious to the user. Like type "san" and get not just "San Francisco" and "San Diego" but also "Thousand Oaks, California". (See the "san" in thouSANd?) Two, SQL can't use an index when a LIKE clause begins with a wildcard, so a search like this would mean a full-file scan every time. And if you hope to find Boston when the user enters "Beantown" or New York when the user enters "big apple", you're in a whole different realm.

If you want a wide range of variations to work, I think you'll need a table of nicknames. In that case, I'd create a "place" table that does not include the name of the place. Then create a place_name table that has all variations on the name that you want to accept. Create a many-to-one relationship between place_name and place. Include a field in place_name that identifies which is the "primary name". Then the query becomes:

```
select n2.name, p.place_id, <whatever>
from place_name n 
join place p on n.place_id=p.place_id
join place_name n2 on n2.place_id=n.place_id and n2.is_primary=1
where n.name like concat(@name,'%') or abbrev(n.name)=@name;
```

For places with only one name, there is only one place_name record for that place.

I say to put all names in the place_name table rather than just alternate names so that you only have to search one table instead of two to find the place. It simplifies the query both for the human reader and for the db engine.